# JPQL select value of DiscriminatorValue column

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I have an entity which looks like this

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "status_type", length = 1, discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorOptions(force = true)
@Table(name = "EnrollmentStatus")
@AttributeOverride(name = AbstractGeneratedUUIDEntity.ID_NAME, column = @Column(name = EnrollmentStatus.ENROLLMENT_STATUS_ID_COLUMN, length = 36))
public abstract class EnrollmentStatus extends AbstractGeneratedUUIDEntity {
}
```

Then there are subsclasses of EnrollmentStatus which look like this:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("E")
public class EnrollmentStatusEnrolled extends EnrollmentStatus {
}
```

I need to write JPQL query which select `status_type`. The only solution I figure out is this:

```
SELECT new com.casenet.dao.enrollment.TimelineProgramEnrollmentQueryResult(prog.id, stat.date, TYPE(stat))
FROM ProgramEnrollment prog
INNER JOIN prog.statuses stat
WHERE prog.obsolete = 0
AND (stat.date >= :startDate and stat.date <= :endDate)
ORDER BY stat.date ASC
```

The problem is TYPE(stat) doesn't select value `E` as String which I expect but `Class` with bunch of metadata. I can access DiscriminatorValue in java like this but it's not nice at all.

```
public TimelineProgramEnrollmentQueryResult(String enrollmentId, LocalDate statusDate, Object status) {
    this.enrollmentId = enrollmentId;
    this.statusDate = statusDate;
    Annotation[] declaredAnnotations = ((Class) status).getDeclaredAnnotations();
    for (Annotation annoation : declaredAnnotations) {
        if (annoation instanceof DiscriminatorValue) {
            this.statusType = ((DiscriminatorValue) annoation).value();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there an elegant way to select `DiscriminatorValue` (not as TYPE but as a value in my case it should be String) from JPQL query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no other JPA approach.

But you could map the column status_type as a readonly attribute:

```
@Column(name = "status_type", insertable=false, updateable=false)
private String statusType;
```

And then use this attribute in your query.